# Show notification when unlocking iPhone

Tags: iphone, notifications

Is there a way to show a notification upon unlocking an iPhone? For example, I want to set a reminder to "do x" at 5 pm, but I don't unlock my phone until 5:30, but I would like the alert to pop up as soon as I unlock it.

Comment: No, I don't believe there's a way to do this

Comment: You can make a reminder with the preinstalled iOS reminders app and it will longer on your lockscreen until you mark it as done.

Comment: @JohnRamos Yeah, I just wanted to make it more noticeable as soon as I unlock my phone

Comment: There will be a badge icon (1) on the reminders app showing you that you have a new reminder, but that's it.